# How to deploy angular app to asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have ASP.NET app with rest service. In the other hand i have dist folder from angular app. Index.html should be in root of app. How to add to visual studio solution this angular app - i want to compile visual studio app with angular app in main and rest api on same domain because of cors.

Comment: I suggest you to have look at this:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/12/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-1-configuring-grunt-uglify-and-angularjs

Comment: i want to create angular app independly, then build it with grunt and then dist folder copy to mvc.net solution.