# deploy ssr angular app in iis

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, universal

I created an angular 2 project, and recently upgraded it to angular 4 with ssr support. In previous version after build in dist folder we had some files and for deploy we copy files to "wwwroot" folder of our ASP.NET Core app and everything was fine.

But now when I build angular app with these commands:

```
ng build -prod --build-optimizer --app 0
sw-precache --root=dist/browser --config=src/sw-precache-config.js --verbose
ng build --aot --app 1
webpack
```

result is two folders and a "server.js" file.
I can't understand how to deploy these 2 folders (browser, server) and 1 file (server.js).

I read these articles but they didn't help me:

https://www.8sph.com/blog/node-iis-virtual-dirs

https://domantasjovaisas.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/expressjs-applications-on-iis-using-iisnode/

https://itsmebhavin.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/iisnode-installation-configuration/

and every question like my question are unanswered in SO:

[How to deploy angular universal in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907440/how-to-deploy-angular-universal-in-iis)

[How to deploy angular app to asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966281/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: are you got any solution?. if yes share to me thanks